# How to return array index with $indexOfArray

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure in Mongo:

```
{
    "participantIdentities": [
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "Summ1",
                "otherData": "Whatever"
            },
            "participantId": 1
        },
        {
            "player": {
                "summonerName": "Summ2",
                "otherData": "Whatever2"
            },
            "participantId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to return the index of one of the elements, so I can then pass that to the next part of the pipeline but it's throwing an error.

Code:

```
db.match.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$project": {
                "matchedIndex": {
                    "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$participantIdentities", {"$player.summonerName": {$eq: "Summ2"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Error:

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$participantIdentities.player.summonerName'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm not sure if querying the current array's elements is supported which might be the issue?

In the example above, I'd want it to return the second element's array index (where summonerName is Summ2) i.e. {"matchedIndex": 1}. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you [look at the usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) it actually tells you. That the "array" is the first argument and the second argument is a "search expression" that **must** produce a value for an equality check.

So rather than write the expression to "test an element equality" you instead "point to the element in the array to test". Which means notating like `"$participantIdentities.player.summonerName"` in order to simply test against the `"name"` properties as a converted array:

```
db.match.aggregate([
 { "$project": {
   "matchedIndex": {
     "$indexOfArray": [
       "$participantIdentities.player.summonerName",
       "Summ2"
     ]
   }
 }}
])
```

The notation basically takes the source array and makes it appear as follows for comparison:

```
[ "Summ1", "Summ2" ]
```

Or if you prefer, then think of the above as with the JavaScript equivalent idiom, using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
participantIdentities.map( p => p.player.summonerName ).indexOf("Summ2")
```

Which is the same thing from a practical standpoint. So even

```
"$participantIdentities.player.summonerName"
```

is essentially "shorthand" for using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator of MongoDB.

And then in comparison, since the "second index" which is `n-1` or `1` is the match, then that value is returned.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I thought you just had to specify the root of the array, and then trim it down rather than just specifying the actual full path and it'll return the index of the top-level array.

Comment: On another note, can I then use the value in matchedIndex to look up the array in another $project?

Comment: @Ashley Combined usage with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) is actually the most common use case. Ideally you do all operations in a "single" `$project` by stacking the calls within each other. In fact the aforementioned `$arrayElemAt` is used with `$indexOfArray` in order to avoid the stacking using `$map` and `$filter`. But if you have new questions then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and make your intended use clear. That's how to ask for additional information.